# Passing an initialization list to a macro

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor

Why doesn't the commented out line in the following program compile?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#define F1(a) 1

int F2(vector<int>) { return 2; }

int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    v = vector<int>{1,2,3};

    cout << F1( v ) << endl;
    //The following line doesn't compile. The error is:
    //error: macro "F" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 1
    //cout << F1( vector<int>{1,2,3} ) << endl; // <- error!
    cout << F1( vector<int>({1,2,3}) ) << endl;
    cout << F1( (vector<int>{1,2,3}) ) << endl;

    cout << F2( v ) << endl;
    //The following line compiles fine
    cout << F2( vector<int>{1,2,3} ) << endl;
    cout << F2( vector<int>({1,2,3}) ) << endl;
    cout << F2( (vector<int>{1,2,3}) ) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The preprocessor does not know about `{}` initialisation. It sees the comma and thinks that's the start of a new macro argument. And then the next one. Only brackets `()` are things that it knows about.

> `[C++11: 16.3/11]:` The sequence of preprocessing tokens bounded by the outside-most matching parentheses forms the list of arguments for the function-like macro. The individual arguments within the list are separated by comma preprocessing tokens, but comma preprocessing tokens between matching inner parentheses do not separate arguments. *[..]*

Comment: The [GCC online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html) has a nice example and explanation.

Comment: Correct. However, that feels like a bug in the C++ specification. The curly braces need to be taken into  account starting with C++11.

Answer (score 15):

A workaround is to transform your **MACRO** into a [variadic MACRO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro)

```
#define F1(...) 1
```

Or in a more general case; turn:

```
#define M(a) a
```

into this:

```
#define M(...) __VA_ARGS__
```

Answer (score 14):

A macro is not a function. It interprets your input `vector<int>{1,2,3}` as 3 inputs, which are `vector<int>{1`,`2` and `3}`. You can change this by making it an expression `(vector<int>{1,2,3})` (as you already did).

Everything in parantheses is an expression <del>and `vector<int>(...)` is a (*special member-)function so the preprocessor sees it as one expression</del>.

Comment: @Light Dammit - you were a little faster :P I corrected it. Is it right now?

Comment: Still, `vector<int>(...)` here is _not_ a function call. Yes, I know it looks like you're calling the constructor.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If it is not a function call, what is it? Unless you meant that constructing an object is not an explicit call to the constructor.