# C++11 issue with GTest

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest

I am writing unit tests for an application. I have some exceptions in a constructor, so I wrote this:

```
TEST(Tablier, ConstructeurParamInvalide2)
{
    ASSERT_THROW(Tablier t_tablier{10, 65} , PreconditionException);
}
```

When I write this, it seems the macro ASSERT_THROW is not satisfied and the test fails. Here is the macro expansion:

```
switch (0) case 0: default: \
  if (::testing::internal::ConstCharPtr gtest_msg = "") { \
    bool gtest_caught_expected = false; \
    try { \
      if (::testing::internal::AlwaysTrue()) { Tablier t_tablier{10; }; \
    } \
    catch (65} const&) { \
      gtest_caught_expected = true; \
    } \
    catch (...) { \
      gtest_msg.value = \
          "Expected: " "Tablier t_tablier{10" " throws an exception of type " \
          "65}" ".\n  Actual: it throws a different type."; \
      goto gtest_label_testthrow_76; \
    } \
    if (!gtest_caught_expected) { \
      gtest_msg.value = \
          "Expected: " "Tablier t_tablier{10" " throws an exception of type " \
          "65}" ".\n  Actual: it throws nothing."; \
      goto gtest_label_testthrow_76; \
    } \
  } else \
    gtest_label_testthrow_76: \
      return ::testing::internal::AssertHelper(::testing::TestPartResult::kFatalFailure, "/home/eric/Programming/cpp/Puissance4/pxTestsUnitaires/tests/test_Tablier.cpp", 76, gtest_msg.value) \
    = ::testing::Message()
```

Notice the `Tablier t_tablier{10; };` Instead, if I write this:

```
TEST(Tablier, ConstructeurParamInvalide2)
{
    ASSERT_THROW(Tablier t_tablier(10, 65) , PreconditionException);
}
```

The macro works fine and the test passes. My project and compiler are configured for C++11, and many other tests pass using C++11 syntax. Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an initialization list to a macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372148/passing-an-initialization-list-to-a-macro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
ASSERT_THROW(Tablier t_tablier(10, 65) , PreconditionException);
ASSERT_THROW(Tablier (10, 65) , PreconditionException);
```

since the macro expansion think the comma between 10 and 65 is macro parameter delimiter. The parentheses is there to tell compiler which one is delimiter.

From [cpp.replace](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.replace#11)

> The sequence of preprocessing tokens bounded by the outside-most matching parentheses forms the list of arguments for the function-like macro. **The individual arguments within the list are separated by comma preprocessing tokens, but *comma preprocessing tokens between matching inner parentheses do not separate arguments*.**

Comment: Macro stopped complaining. Thanks!

Comment: BTW your last edit is exactly what was shown as already working in my question...